# Finding number with specified collatz sequence length

Tags: python, math, collatz

I need to make a program that finds a number with specified collatz sequence length. However, there is always a problem that the program is too slow. For example my current best score that i could get was number with collatz sequence length of 1200 (I need to be able to get number with collatz sequence length of 1800).

I tried a lot of diffrent methods, but the best one so far was trying to recreate collatz number tree.[Here is an example from wiki](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BssLo.png). As I said before i need to be able to get a number with collatz sequence length of 1800 but I cant get more than 1200.

That's my current solution (I know it's complicated but other methods I tried so far were able to get collatz sequence length up to 500 only):

```
A = int(input())

limit = 1000000000000000000

def runCollaz(ciag):

    steps = 0

    while ciag != 1:
        
        if (ciag % 2 == 0):
            ciag /= 2
        else:
            ciag *= 3
            ciag += 1
        steps+=1
    return steps

def makeChainLess(number):
    if (number % 2 == 0):
        return number / 2
    else:
        return ((number * 3) + 1)

collatzTree = [[1, 1]]

finallAns = "None"

def getAns(collatzTree, what):    
    awnser = "None"

    if (collatzTree[0][0] < limit and collatzTree[0][1] == A):
        awnser = collatzTree[0][0]

    while (len(collatzTree) > 250):
        currentHigh = collatzTree[0][0]
        highIndex = 0
        index = 0
        for x in collatzTree:
            if (x[0] > currentHigh):
                currentHigh = x[0]
                highIndex = index
            index += 1
        collatzTree.pop(highIndex)
            

    if (collatzTree[0][0] > 4):
        if (collatzTree[0][0] - 1) % 3 == 0:
            if (collatzTree[0][0] - 1) % 2 != 0:
                collatzTree += [[(collatzTree[0][0] - 1) / 3, int(collatzTree[0][1]) + 1]]
            collatzTree += [[collatzTree[0][0] * 2, int(collatzTree[0][1]) + 1]]
            collatzTree.pop(0)
        else:
            collatzTree += [[collatzTree[0][0] * 2, int(collatzTree[0][1]) + 1]]
            collatzTree.pop(0)

    else:
        collatzTree += [[collatzTree[0][0] * 2, int(collatzTree[0][1]) + 1]]
        collatzTree.pop(0)
    if (what == "C"):
        return collatzTree
    else:
        return awnser

while finallAns == "None":
    finallAns = getAns(collatzTree, "A")
    collatzTree = getAns(collatzTree, "C")
print(int(finallAns))
```

If anyone could help i would really appricate it.

Comment: Why don't you just set your limit higher? Do you know that the number you're seeking is within that limit?

Comment: Doesn't 2\*\*k have a collatz sequence length of k? Perhaps you're looking for the *smallest* number with sequence length of k.

Comment: Maybe dups of this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69917883/

Comment: No, that dup is for a related but distinct problem. The problem here is to find an implementation for the *inverse* of the `find_length` method of the answer for that dup.

Comment: If this is in Python 3, it would make more sense to use `//3` rather than `/3` and skip the later calls to `int()`. Avoiding the type conversions should help some.

Comment: So about that setting higher limit i forgot to mention that max number that can be in output is 10^18. About 2**k that wont work as well because number is too large for sequence length of 200 and I need 1800. Also changing /3 for //3 make it able to get numbers up to 1400.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code that takes only a few minutes to run for 10 million.  It just needs more computing power, which is kind of the story on Collatz.

```
'''
This code finds numbers that have the specified Collatz sequence length
(by brute force)
'''
import time
start = time.time()                      #start code timer

n = 1                                        #set low end of range
for number in range (10000000, n-1, -1):   #work down from max range
     num = number
     trial = 0
     while number > 1:                 #set up looping until 1 is reached
            
         if number % 2 == 0:         #set up normal Collatz sequence comp.
              number = number // 2             
                             
         else:
              number = (number * 3) + 1
                           
         trial = trial+1                  #update counter for each loop
         if number == 1 and trial == 500 or trial == 600:  #set target numbers
                  #print all numbers where specified target occured:
              print("Number with sequence "
                    "length of {0}: {1}".format(trial, num))
                                         
if number == n:
     print("end of range")                #tells user that code has ended

end = time.time()
print("elapsed time: ",end - start)
```

Comment: I'm afraid you dont know what I mean. The program is supposed to get number with chain length of 1800 in 10 seconds. My original program is able to get a number with collatz sequence length of 1400 in less than 10 seconds. So im afraid that your program is even slower than my original version

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of the extremely short time constraints.  I am using a 10 year old i5 desktop.  With your code, I can get an answer for 1200 in just a few seconds, but 1400 didn't finish in 10 minutes for me.  But, you're right, my code doesn't even come close to your speeds.

Comment: It's an intriguing problem, I noticed that your code seems to work fine if the limit could be set higher, as suggested in the comment by MattDMo above.

Comment: Sadly limit has to be exaclly 10^18, but if you change limit of collatz tree length it's way slower